# AngularJS function not called in the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

it's an hour I'm trying to understand why a function I defined inside a controller of an AngularJS project is not being called.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('SupplierPortal', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

**userLoginController.js**

```
angular.module('SupplierPortal').controller('UserLoginController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.text = "Hi";

  $scope.login = function() {
    console.log('It doesn't show this');
    $location.path(/admin);
  }
});
```

**login.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="account-wall">
            <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
                alt="">
            <form class="form-signin">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('SupplierPortal').config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "assets/templates/users/login.html",
    controller: "UserLoginController"
})
.when("/admin/", {
  templateUrl: "assets/templates/users/index_admin.html"
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo:'/'
});
```

});

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="SupplierPortal">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view class="container"></div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->

<!-- Vendor -->
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/routes.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="assets/javascript/controllers/users/userLoginController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="assets/javascript/services/user.js"></script>
```

It does not show the text in the console, and of course it does not go to /admin/ path.

Thanks to everyone will try to help me!

Comment: Sorry for the message in the console.log(), I wrote it only to show you the point, it's not the real message and so there is not the problem of the " ' " that closes the string to log in the console.

Comment: Any errors in console?, also what about the quotes in `$location.path("/admin")`?

Answer (score 0):

fix the following line:

```
console.log('It doesn't show this');
```

the string is being closed with "'" in the middle of the sentence, because you used "doens't". either use " or dont use ' on the "doens't" word